# Gremlin DSL usage errors within `repeat` step

Tags: javascript, gremlin, dsl, tinkerpop3

We are using `gremlin-javascript` and have recently started to define a DSL to simplify our queries.

I am not sure if I've overlooked some caveat, but when attempting to use DSL methods within a `repeat` step, I consistently receive `(...).someDslFunction is not a function` errors, but using the same DSL function outside of `repeat` works without issue.

Here is a short (contrived) DSL definition that produces this issue:

```js
class CustomDSLTraversal extends GraphTraversal {
  constructor(graph, traversalStrategies, bytecode) {
    super(graph, traversalStrategies, bytecode);
  }

  hasNotLabel(...args) {
    return this.not(__.hasLabel(...args));
  }

  filterNotLabel(...args) {
    return this.filter(__.hasNotLabel(...args));
  }
}

class CustomDSLTraversalSource extends GraphTraversalSource {
  constructor(graph, traversalStrategies, bytecode) {
    super(graph, traversalStrategies, bytecode, CustomDSLTraversalSource, CustomDSLTraversal);
  }
}

const statics = {
  hasNotLabel: (...args) => callOnEmptyTraversal('hasNotLabel', args),
  ...gremlin.process.statics
};

const __ = statics;
const g = traversal(CustomDSLTraversalSource).withRemote(connection);
```

And here are two uses of it, the first works without issue, the second causes the `__.outE().(...).filterNotLabel is not a function` error.

```js
g.V('foo').outE().filterNotLabel('x', 'y').otherV(); // No errors
```

```js
g.V('foo').repeat(__.outE().filterNotLabel('x', 'y').otherV()).times(1); // Error

// __.outE(...).filterNotLabel is not a function
```

**EDIT**: Thanks @stephen for pointing out the now so obvious issue:

I had redefined `callOnEmptyTraversal` for use with our DSL, and foolishly destructured the standard TinkerPop anonymous traversals into our custom ones. These obviously are calling the original `callOnEmptyTraversal` which does indeed use an instance of the base `GraphTraversal`.

```js
function callOnEmptyTraversal(fn, args) {
  const g = new CustomDSLTraversal(null, null, new Bytecode());
  return g[fn].apply(g, args);
}

const statics = {
  hasNotLabel: (...args) => callOnEmptyTraversal('hasNotLabel', args),
  mapToObject: (...args) => callOnEmptyTraversal('mapToObject', args),
  ...gremlin.process.statics // Whoops
};

const __ = statics;
```

**SOLUTION:** Just in case anyone else runs into this scenario. This is how I solved the issue of merging our DSL anonymous traversal spawns with the standard TinkerPop ones:

```js
function callOnEmptyTraversal(fn, args) {
  const g = new CustomDSLTraversal(null, null, new Bytecode());
  return g[fn].apply(g, args);
}

function mapToCallOnEmptyTraversal(s, fn) {
  s[fn] = (...args) => callOnEmptyTraversal(fn, args);
  return s;
}

const statics = ['hasNotLabel', 'mapToObject']
 .concat(Object.keys(gremlin.process.statics))
 .reduce(mapToCallOnEmptyTraversal, {});

const __ = statics;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the problem is that it's because you start your traversal with `__` which is the standard TinkerPop spawn for anonymous traversals. As a result you get a `GraphTraversal` created rather than your `CustomDSLTraversalSource`. The TinkerPop gremlin-javascript [documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-javascript-dsl) states that:

> steps that are made available on a GraphTraversal should also be made available as spawns for anonymous traversals

So you probably should have your own version of `__` that returns the `CustomDSLTraversalSource`. If you want to see more explicitly where things are going wrong, see [in the code](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.4.4/gremlin-javascript/src/main/javascript/gremlin-javascript/lib/process/graph-traversal.js#L1247-L1249) that `callOnEmptyTraversal()` returns `GraphTraversal` and obviously your DSL methods won't be available on that class.